# passing intent value to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Why the value did not appear in the second activity which is consultDoctorAnaemia? I think the code is already correct. But it display null.

resultAnaemia

```
if(symptom16.equals("Yes"))
{                                 
   weight=0.11;                                                  
   newWeight = 0.0 * 0.15; //cf disease = 0.6, [min=0.15]                               
   String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);


   Intent intent = new Intent(resultAnemia.this, consultDoctorAnaemia.class);

   intent.putExtra("cfDiseases", cf);

   startActivity(intent);

}
```

consultDoctorAnaemia

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCF);

    //get passed intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(null != intent)
    {
        //get cf value from intent
        String cf = intent.getStringExtra("cfDiseases");
        textView.setText("Certainty value : " + cf);
    }
```

Comment: In what method are you executing the code you posted from `consultDoctorAnaemia`? Also, post your manifest and explain the navigation between activities (ie: which activities are already active when you call `startActivity()` to launch `consultDoctorAnaemia`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String Diseases = extras.getString("cfDiseases");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in the consultDoctorAnaemia activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

String value2 = bundle.getString("cfDiseases");
```

Comment: Nonsense! This code does **exactly the same thing** as OP's posted code!

Comment: calling `getStringExtra()` on an `Intent` does **exactly the same thing** as what you've posted. Try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in first activity:

```
// do your intent setup somewhere and then setup bundle
Bundle info = new Bundle();
info.putString("cfDiseases", cf);
intent.putExtras(info);
startActivity(intent);
```

In new activity:
    Bundle info = new Bundle();
    info = getIntent().getExtras();
    cf = info.getString("cfDiseases");

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass value like this way

Declare your string global and static For example

Declare in variable in this class

**Class A**

```
public class A extends Activity{

static String cf = "abcde";


}
```

Access variable in this B class

**class B**

```
public class B extends Activity{
String Temp;

//you can get variable like this
Temp=A.cf ;
Toast.makeText(B.this, "Temp = "+Temp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```